# Búsqueda por caracteres Árabes en SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una base de datos donde una tabla tiene un campo llamado `textoArabe` que es de tipo `nvarchar(1000)` que permite guardar textos tanto en escritura latina (europea) y escritura con caracteres árabes.

El problema se me presenta cuando intento buscar por un caracter árabe y no me encuentra nada.

Por ejemplo, tengo un registro en el que esta escrito lo siguiente (que ni se lo que significa), en donde he mezclado ambos caracteres:

```
بورتريه للشخdfdsص الع
```

Cuando pongo la consulta:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [PRUEBA]
  where textoArabe like'%d%'
```

Me devuelve correctamente el texto, pero si pongo:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM [PRUEBA]
  where textoArabe like'%ل%'
```

No me devuelve nada.

Agradecería si alguien me puede indicar como hacer la búsqueda por caracteres árabes.

Comment: qué tipo de dato es la columna `textoarabe`?, me imagino que es `NVARCHAR`, por lo que la comparación que deberías estar haciendo es `WHERE textoarabe LIKE N'%ل%'`, para asegurar que entiende que es `NVARCHAR`

Comment: gracias @Lamak, efectivamente, es NVARCHAR y con la N delante funciona, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta agregando `N` al inicio de la cadena que deseas comparar, por ejemplo, yo realicé el siguiente ejercicio. Suponiendo que en la definición del campo `Arabic` tienes el `COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS`, sino de otra solo se almacenarán signos de interrogación donde no se logre interpretar un caracter:

```
CREATE TABLE ArabicTextTest
(
    Arabic VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS
)

INSERT INTO ArabicTextTest 
VALUES(N'بورتريه للشخdfdsص الع')

SELECT * FROM ArabicTextTest
WHERE Arabic = N'بورتريه للشخdfdsص الع'

SELECT * FROM ArabicTextTest
WHERE Arabic LIKE N'%ل%'
```